# Calculate / detect dropped frames in video?

Tags: video, video-processing

I have two video files that I'd like to have near-perfect synchrony if possible. The problem is that one seems to be dropping frames like crazy. The computer that recorded the videos wasn't that great, so I assume that is the main reason!

I was wondering: is there any piece of software, script or ... anything else... that I can use to work out how many frames were present in the video for each second of footage? I'd like to check both videos in case both are dropping frames. For output, I was hoping for something like:

Second | 1; 2; 3 
Frames | 25; 21; 25

With the number of frames listed for each second of video footage. Here, second 2 has only 21 frames, and seconds 1 and 3 both have 25. That should be a table with "Second" and "Frames" as headings, but I can't seem to get the formatting right ^^

Any pointers would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the video physically has the correct and steady framerate, with some adjacent frames being identical, which creates an impression of variable frame rate and lags.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. When I play the videos side-by-side there is a definite sign of lag that somehow appears, with one overtaking the other. How do these identical frames cause that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the element using `getElementById()` by passing id of the element as the parameter. then using that object you can get the `droppedVideoFrames`.

```
var videoObj=document.getElementById("videoId");//this is id of your html video tag
var dframe=videoObj.droppedVideoFrames;
console.log("droped frame = "+dframe);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.